# Improve PostgreSQL pg_restore Performance from 130 hours

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, pg-restore, timescaledb

I am trying to improve the time taken to restore a PostgreSQL database backup using `pg_restore`. The 29 GB gzip-compressed backup file is created from a 380 GB PostgreSQL database using `pg_dump -Z0 -Fc` piped into `pigz`.

During `pg_restore`, the database size is increasing at a rate of 50 MB/minute estimated using the `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size())` query. At this rate, it will take approximately 130 hours to complete the restore which is a very long time.

On further investigation, it appears that the CPU usage is low despite setting `pg_restore` to use 4 workers.

[image]

The disk write speed and IOPS are also very low:

[image]
[image]

Benchmarking the system's IO using `fio` has shown that it can do 300 MB/s writes and 2000 IOPS, so we are utilizing only about 20% of the potential IO capabilities.

Is there any way to speed up the database restore?

**System**

- Ubuntu 18.04.3
- 1 vCPU, 2 GB RAM, 4GB Swap
- 500 GB ZFS (2-way mirror array)
- PostgreSQL 11.6
- TimescaleDB 1.60

**Steps taken to perform restore:**

1. Decompress the .gz file to `/var/lib/postgresql/backups/backup_2020-02-29` (~ 40mins)
2. Modify `postgresql.conf` settings

```
work_mem = 32MB
shared_buffers = 1GB            
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB      
full_page_writes = off
autovacuum = off
wal_buffers = -1
```

3. `pg_ctl restart`
4. Run the following commands inside `psql`:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_development;
\c database_development
CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb;
SELECT timescaledb_pre_restore();

\! time pg_restore -j 4 -Fc -d database_development /var/lib/postgresql/backups/backup_2020-02-29

SELECT timescaledb_post_restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database system is I/O bound, as you can see from the `%iowait` value of 63.62.

Increasing `maintenance_work_mem` might improve the situation a little, but essentially you need faster storage.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity of VM memory is significantly too low to run properly the system, pg executables and data in cache. Set the VM memory to 8 Gb and fix it in the VM (reserve all guest memory). Also 1 cpu/1core is very low too...